# Html Parsing using Xerces c++

Tags: c++, html-parsing, xerces, xerces-c

I'm trying to parse a local html page using Xerces in c++ but I don't know how to parse special characters like "©", when parser came across with one of that characters the entire TextNode is not parsed .Does anyone know how to parse that characters.